# How do I customize android os for a smartglass?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to make custom os for a smartglass but I have no experience AOSP where should I start from and what are the things that I should take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

As for me, first you need to think about the DevKit, which is supported by AOSP out of the box. For example, in my projects I use HiKey960. The link below describes the basic steps of getting AOSP sources, building them, and target flashing: https://source.android.com/setup/build/devices#960userspace

Once you have buildable and runable AOSP, you can try adding your own functionality: application, services, native daemons, HAL implementation, and so on.